# "[ErrorException] chmod(): Operation not permitted" running "composer update"

Tags: composer, file-permissions

I'm running Magento 2.4.2 and I'm using Composer v2.0.11. 2 days ago, after running, as usual, *composer update*, I suddenly received this error:

```
[ErrorException]
chmod(): Operation not permitted
```

You can see `composer update -v` output down below:

[image]

#### What I tried

- I tried to apply `chmod -R 777 .` and `chown -R www-data:www-data .`
- I tried to apply chmod u+x bin/magento

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the filesystem ownership to the magento user (*dev* in my case, while before was assigned to *www-data* user) fixed the problem: `chown -R dev:www-data .`

Comment: Be sure to undo your chmod command if you successfully executed it, 777 permissions on the whole Magento filesystem is potentially very dangerous

Comment: Yeah, thanks for point this out. In developer mode I set them like this as described in the Magento doc: `cd /var/www/magento && find . var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento`

Comment: While in Production `cd /var/www/magento && find . var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento`

Answer (score 0):

For windows

```
rm -rf vendor && composer install
```

For Ubuntu

```
sudo rm -rf vendor && sudo composer install
```